# Unity3D changes not showing in build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a basic 2D Android quiz game in Unity 3D. The issue is that certain changes are not passing through to the build even though they are visible and working in the editor. I am using Unity 2019.4.1f1(64bit) on Windows 10(x64). What I have tried so far:

- Closed down Unity and stopped the background service, removed previous instances of the build, restarted Unity and rebuilt;
- Deleted the Library folder and retried the build;
- On the mobile I am testing the app, I have done factory reset and reinstalled the app.

I have restarted the Windows 10 Laptop between each test.

Any other suggestions as to why the build is not being created with the most up to date scripts?

**EDIT**

I have kind of got to the bottom of the issue. The cause seems to be my Level Select Scene. I am using a json file to hold player data including:

- Player Name;
- Last completed Level(for activation/deactivation of level buttons;
- Level Score;
- Level completion status as a boolean.

I am using a separate function in a script called Player.cs(LoadLastLevel) to obtain the last completed level number. Data extraction from the json is achieved using SimpleJSON, here is the code for the two areas affected:

**LevelSelectController.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using SimpleJSON;

public class LevelSelectController : MonoBehaviour
{
    static public int currentLevel;
    public Font kb_Font;
    public List<Button> buttonsList = new List<Button>();
    public int lastCompletedLevel;
    public Player player;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        int l = player.LoadLastLevel();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < buttonsList.Count; i++)
        {
            int levelNum = i;
            buttonsList[i].onClick.AddListener(() => {currentLevel = levelNum;});

            buttonsList[i].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().fontSize  = 48;
            buttonsList[i].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().font  = kb_Font;

            buttonsList[i].GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.grey;
        
            if (i > l)
            {
                buttonsList[i].interactable = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void StartLevel()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("Game");
    }

    public void ReturnToMenu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("MenuScreen");
    }
}
```

**Player.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using SimpleJSON;
using System.IO;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string playerName;
    public int lastCompletedLevel;

    public int Load()
    {
        string filePath = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/data.json";
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        JSONObject playerJson = (JSONObject)JSON.Parse(jsonString);

        playerName = playerJson["player"]["playerName"];
        lastCompletedLevel = playerJson["player"]["lastCompletedLevel"];

        return lastCompletedLevel;
    }

    public int LoadLastLevel()
    {
        string filePath = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/data.json";
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        JSONObject playerJson = (JSONObject)JSON.Parse(jsonString);

        lastCompletedLevel = playerJson["player"]["lastCompletedLevel"];

        return lastCompletedLevel;
    }

    public void SavePlayerData(int completedLevel, int levelScore)
    {
        string filePath = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/data.json";
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        JSONObject playerJson = (JSONObject)JSON.Parse(jsonString);

        playerJson["player"]["lastCompletedLevel"] = completedLevel;
        playerJson["player"]["levels"][completedLevel][2] = levelScore;
        playerJson["player"]["levels"][completedLevel][1] = true;

        string myJsonString = (playerJson.ToString());
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, myJsonString);
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

I manually set the value of 'l' in the LevelSelectController.cs script, it worked. I then set the value of 'l' manually in the Player.cs to rule out an issue with the JSON portion of the script, it failed. So I believe the root cause  to be that the build is not bringing in the Player.cs script and therefore the call to *player.LoadLastLevel()* in the LevelSelectController.cs script is failing.

I suspect that the issue is with how I am calling *player.LoadLastLevel()*, should I be calling the GameObject the script is attached to?

**EDIT TWO**

I think I have the cause of the issue, after using adb to inspect the logcat on the device as the application runs, I am getting an *DirectoryNotFoundException* when looking for my JSON file in the *StreamingAssets* folder so I believe that by problem line is here:

```
string filePath = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/data.json";
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve would be most welcomed?

**EDIT THREE**

I jumped the gun by setting an Answer to this question. Whilst the code provided below happily reads from data.json, it will not write to it:

```
public int LoadLastLevel()
    {         
        string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "data.json");
    string jsonString;

        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        {
            UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(filePath);
            www.SendWebRequest();
            while (!www.isDone) ;
            jsonString = www.downloadHandler.text;
        }
        else
        {
        jsonString = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        }

        JSONObject playerJson = (JSONObject)JSON.Parse(jsonString);

        lastCompletedLevel = playerJson["player"]["lastCompletedLevel"];

        return lastCompletedLevel;
    }
```

I have been able to create a *.json file in the persistentDataPath instead using the same code and simply changing the target of *filePath* to persistentDataPath. The issue is that I am not able to subsequently read or edit the file. Reading returns null.

Credit for getting me this far goes to Triple_Why over at the Unity Forum for his response to the message at

https://forum.unity.com/threads/cant-use-json-file-from-streamingassets-on-android-and-ios.472164/

Any further guidance on how to read from/write to a file that is in the persistentDataPath on Android would be welcomed?

Comment: Try to make a local Windows build to make sure that your changes are visible in it. If yes, it's not Unity's fault, make sure you're installing the right apk on your device. 

Also, try to build the apk to a new, simple to find location and install it manually via adb.

Comment: Are you sure the build is actually a new build? Can you check the modified date of the build files?

Comment: I have tried the local windows build and it worked. Definitely the correct APK as I changed version number to verify. Will try the second suggestions once I fire up a Linux device. I am certain the APK build file is new for the reason stated. Will feedback once I have tested the suggestions.

Comment: Have successfully created a new apk and verified that it is new by creating it in c:\temp, installed it via ADB, installs without error, but the content is still out of date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was a frustratingly simple solution, after examining the logcat of the device and seen curl errors, this pointed me to the cause being that the intent of *UnityWebRequest* is the querying of the streamingAssetsPath, I am no longer using this so I just had to remove reference to *UnityWebRequest* and go back to reading the data using *File.ReadAllText* and *voila*, just like that it started working.

```
public int LoadLastLevel()
{         
    string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerdata.json";
    string jsonString;

    jsonString = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

    JSONObject playerJson = (JSONObject)JSON.Parse(jsonString);

    lastCompletedLevel = playerJson["player"]["lastCompletedLevel"];

    Debug.Log("Player name is " + playerName + " and the last completed level is " + lastCompletedLevel);
    Debug.Log("The filePath to PlayerData.JSON is " + filePath);

    return lastCompletedLevel;
}
```

Hope this helps anyone else facing a similar issue.